# Symfony 4 - Send POST request with multipart/form-data

Tags: symfony

I want to send a POST request to register my users, but I don't want to type my login and password in the URL, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESR7D.png). I wanted to use the multipart/form-data format, to send my arguments as if they were in a form, like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaKvb.png).

Do you know how can I do that?

Thanks in advance! ^^

Comment: Clicking on random internet images is a good way to inject your computer will all sorts of nasty malware.  Consider updating your question such that it can be answered.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be related to Symfony at all, wrong tags. `multipart/form-data` is an attributed set with `enctype` on `form` tags needed to upload files, not related to login/password. Make your question more clear please.

Comment: Like already said in the comments, your question is really ambiguous.
Can you explain us what are you exactly trying to do ? Are you building an API using Symfony ? If so, are you asking how to build a sign up form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I used $request->request->get() to extract my values , like this :

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$user = new User();
$user->setLogin($request->request->get('login'));
$user->setPassword($request->request->get('password'));
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

And then I serialize my values in a JSON object, it's working perfectly ^^ Thanks for your help! ^^

Comment: `$request->request->get('login')` can be simplified down to `$request->get('login')`, but dude, please, validate the input first.

Comment: No, $request->get('login') gets the parameters passed in the URL, and not the parameters from the JSON object.

Comment: No, [you should check Symfony's source code](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L702) sometimes.

Comment: @emix yeah and you should read the PHPDoc you linked to: https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L682 "it is better to explicitly get request parameters from the appropriate public property instead (attributes, query, request)". So yeah, don't use `$request->get('login')`.

Comment: You should also include the part before that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a POST request to some URL with some data, I suggest encoding the data in json format.
See [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or [Symfony serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) or [jms_serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer).
Or, if you wish, you can send url encoded data, using [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).
Just remember to send the right Content-type header, `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
And to perform the request, consider using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) or [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

I realize I've just provided you with official docummmentation about related stuff, but I haven't fully understood your question, so I tried giving you general pointers for you to research. There are good examples of certain functionallities I believe you will need in order to do this.

Assuming you have the URL to make the request:

1. gather the data to post
2. serialize the gathered data
3. execute the request to the url with the serialized data
4. parse the response body
5. continue doing your logic

In case this isn't what you were looking for, please provide some more context, some code you have (don't share any sensitive data), or something, so you could get more precise answers. I hope I've managed to help. Feel free to ask more questions.